# c# select smaller 3d array from larger 3d array

Tags: c#-4.0, xna

I have an array (object[,,]), let us assume for arguments sake the array is x1000, y1000,z*1000 and represents a matrix of points on an x,y,z plane.

at position: x50,y10,z199, for example I want to extract another object[,,] containing a smaller cube, say a submatrix of 100 cubed(or whatever is available, nulls if empty?) from the parent array using the reference point as a centerpoint, is this possible, I was hoping I could do it in linq but got hopelessly lost.. how would you/ should I tackle this.. one though was to do the following:

1.Create a new 3d array with the size of the amount of items i want to retrieve (xyz).

2.Iterate over each axis (x, y, z).

3.Copy the value from the source array to the target array (offsetX+x, offsetY+y, offsetZ+z).

4.Return new array.

but if this is being called a lot, I see it being quite a bottleneck, ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usage of the smaller array, this may or may not suit your needs.

---

To represent a sub section (chunk) of array, instead of creating a new array or doing any copying, you could write your own class which serves as *a view* to that chunk of array.

Note that this example has the following properties:

- No guard clauses in constructor
- Chunk is always cube (x, y, z length are equal)
- Chunk length is always odd (since we are expanding out from point of reference)

```
public class ArrayChunk<T>
{
    // Array this chunk is from.
    private readonly T[,,] _parentArray;
    // Point of reference.
    private readonly int _x, _y, _z;
    // How many elements to move outwards in each direction from point of reference.
    private readonly int _numToExpand;

    public ArrayChunk(T[,,] parentArray, int x, int y, int z, int numToExpand)
    {
        _parentArray = parentArray;
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _z = z;            
        _numToExpand = numToExpand;
    }

    public int Length => _numToExpand*2 + 1;

    public T this[int x, int y, int z]
    {
        get
        {
            // Make sure index is within chunk range.
            EnsureInChunkRange(x, y, z);
            // Map chunk index to parent array index.
            int parentX = MapToParent(_x, x),
                parentY = MapToParent(_y, y),
                parentZ = MapToParent(_z, z);
            // If parent array index is in parent array range, return element from parent array.
            if (IsInRangeOfParent(parentX, parentY, parentZ))
                return _parentArray[parentX, parentY, parentZ];
            // Otherwise return default element for type T.
            return default(T);
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureInChunkRange(x, y, z);
            int parentX = MapToParent(_x, x),
                parentY = MapToParent(_y, y),
                parentZ = MapToParent(_z, z);
            if (IsInRangeOfParent(parentX, parentY, parentZ))
                _parentArray[parentX, parentY, parentZ] = value;
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }

    private void EnsureInChunkRange(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0 ||
            x >= Length || y >= Length || z >= Length)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private int MapToParent(int referenceIndex, int index)
    {
        return referenceIndex - _numToExpand + index;
    }

    private bool IsInRangeOfParent(int parentX, int parentY, int parentZ)
    {
        return 
            parentX >= 0 && 
            parentY >= 0 && 
            parentZ >= 0 && 
            parentX < _parentArray.GetLength(0) && 
            parentY < _parentArray.GetLength(1) && 
            parentZ < _parentArray.GetLength(2);
    }                
}
```

To easily get chunk from array, you could declare an extension method:

```
public static class ArrayChunkExtensions
{
    public static ArrayChunk<T> GetChunk<T>(this T[,,] array, int x, int y, int z, int numToExpand)
    {
        return new ArrayChunk<T>(array, x, y, z, numToExpand);
    }
}
```

Here's a sample usage:

```
Action<int, Action<int, int, int>> iterate = (length, action) =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
            for (int z = 0; z < length; z++)
                action(x, y, z);
};

// Create 5x5x5 parent array.

const int size = 5;
var array = new string[size, size, size];
iterate(size, (x, y, z) => array[x, y, z] = $"x:{x} y:{y} z:{z}");

// Take 3x3x3 chunk from parent array center.

const int indexOfReference = 2;
const int numToExpand = 1;
ArrayChunk<string> chunk = array.GetChunk(indexOfReference, indexOfReference, indexOfReference, numToExpand);
iterate(chunk.Length, (x, y, z) => Console.WriteLine(chunk[x, y, z]));
```

Comment: Thank you, looks a touch more efficient than what I came up with, I'll try and let you know/mark as answered

Comment: Let me know if you run into any issues or have any questions.